# Nouveau error when attempting to install 16.04

Tags: boot

I am brand new to linux and have no prior experience whatsoever, so please bear with me (I am very excited to learn!).  When attempting to install or even run without installing I get stuck with an error that says "unknown chipset"  and attempting to "write through" so basically I never even get to the splash menu. After the message my monitor reads "mode not supported" and the system reboots (i have an asus rog swift monitor 2560x1440 and a gtx1070 if that means anything). I have tried nomodeset with no success can someone help me out? The error code is 0x00000080 or something like that (plus or minus a 0)

Comment: Have you tried disabling _acpi_?